# Acronyms in section names with classic thesis

Tags: sectioning, acronyms, capitalization, classicthesis

I have troubles using *acronym* package with *classicthesis* package when I put an acronym in a section name. The least reproducible example I could come up with is this:

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}

% If I remove the option 'pdfspacing' I got this error:
%
% ! Argument of \@acl has an extra }.
% <inserted text>
%                 \par
%l.21 \section{\acl{GRASP}}

\usepackage[pdfspacing]{classicthesis}

\usepackage{acronym}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents{}

\chapter{Algorithms}

Details about algorithms.

\section{\acl{GRASP}}

Initial solutions are constructed using \ac{GRASP}.

\chapter{Acronyms}

\begin{acronym}
  \acro{GRASP}{Greedy Randomized Adaptive Search Procedure}
\end{acronym}

\end{document}
```

If I run Latex (three times) I got this warning:

```
...

Package acronym Warning: Acronym `grasp' is not defined on input line 25.


LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `OT1/pplj/bx/sc' undefined
(Font)              using `OT1/pplj/bx/n' instead on input line 25.

[2]
Chapter 2.
[3] (C:\Users\claudio\Desktop\text\thesis.aux)

LaTeX Font Warning: Some font shapes were not available, defaults substituted.

)
(see the transcript file for additional information)pdfTeX warning (dest): name
{GRASP} has been referenced but does not exist, replaced by a fixed one

...
```

And in the PDF the section title says `grasp!`, while other entries are correctly replaced with the acronym.

[image]

The only related line I found in the log file (is that the transcript file?) says this:

```
Package acronym Info: Label `acro:GRASP' newly defined as it shall be overridden
although it is yet undefined on input line 27.
```

But I have no idea how to fix it.

If I comment out the two classicthesis related lines everything is fine.

Comment: @Sveinung As [tag:case-change] is a new tag, please consider to replace it with [tag:capitalization], or at least to add the latter tag. (BTW, +1 for your answer.)

Comment: @lockstep Thank you for finding the correct tag.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The error is due to the fact that `classicthesis` upper- and lowercase the headings. Try using the package `textcase` with the `overload` option and enclose the acronym-command with a `\NoCaseChange` in titles and heading. This MWE compiled fine for me (only one warning regarding an overfull box):

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}

\usepackage[overload]{textcase}
\usepackage[pdfspacing]{classicthesis}
\usepackage{acronym}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents{}

\chapter{Algorithms}
Details about algorithms.

\section{\NoCaseChange{\acl{GRASP}}}
Initial solutions are constructed using \ac{GRASP}.

\chapter{Acronyms}
\begin{acronym}
  \acro{GRASP}{Greedy Randomized Adaptive Search Procedure}
\end{acronym}

\end{document}
```

One comment regarding the typography: You should format the acronym as the text, *i.e*. in spaced small caps (ref:*Bringhurst*).

Comment: Great, now it works (and I guess it is the same reason why indexes did not work either)! I am not sure I understood your last remark, do you mean I should enclose the acronym with `\textsc`? Like `\acro{GRASP}{\textsc{Greedy Randomized Adaptive Search Procedure}}`? Or like `\acro{\textsc{GRASP}}{Greedy Randomized Adaptive Search Procedure}`? Is there a way to make it automatic?

Comment: In `classicthesis` acronyms is typeset with space small caps, as _Bringhurst_ recommends in his book. `classicthesis` has a command, `\spacedlowsmallcaps`, which do that. I tried to redefined the relevant command in `acronym` (see section 2.2 in the `acronym`’s manual), but it did not work. I suggest you ask a new question regarding that, because then one of the gurus for certain will come up with a solution.