# ClassicThesis and acronym warnings: "has been referenced but does not exist, replaced by a fixed one"

Tags: hyperref, acronyms, classicthesis

I'm using ClassicThesis with the acronym package like this (MWE):

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{classicthesis}
\usepackage{acronym}
\begin{document}
\begin{acronym}
\acro{MAP}{Maximum A Posteriori}
\end{acronym}
Document text with an acronym: \ac{MAP}.
\end{document}
```

When compiling with pdflatex in Linux (three times), I get this kind of warning:

```
pdfTeX warning (dest): name{MAP} has been referenced but does not exist, replaced by a fixed one
```

I checked [Acronyms in section names with classic thesis](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/65806/acronyms-in-section-names-with-classic-thesis) and [Classicthesis: Capital abbreviations for acronyms in Acronym section](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/227944/classicthesis-capital-abbreviations-for-acronyms-in-acronym-section), but those are slightly different questions due to ClassicThesis changing the case in headings. Instead, I get that kind of warning consistently for all acronyms (uppercase, lowercase and mixed case).

I attempted `\PassOptionsToPackage{printonlyused,smaller}{acronym}`
as in the example file `classicthesis-config.tex`, but that does not seem to remove the warning. I'm not even sure that `\PassOptionsToPackage` is the best solution. Any suggestion? (In my full document I also need to load package `hyperref`.)

Comment: This seems to be clearly the fault of `classicthesis` . Removing it and loading `hyperref` directly works. `classicthesis` is often the cause of errors. Don't use it!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not so ugly workaround:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}

\usepackage{classicthesis}
\usepackage{acronym}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\makeatletter
\AtBeginEnvironment{acronym}{%
  \def\NRorg@descriptionlabel#1{\hspace{\labelsep}#1}%
  \setkomafont{descriptionlabel}{\normalfont}%
  \renewcommand*{\aclabelfont}[1]{\spacedlowsmallcaps{#1}}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{acronym}
\acro{MAP}{Maximum A Posteriori}
\end{acronym}

Document text with an acronym: \ac{MAP}.

Document text with an acronym: \ac{MAP}.

\end{document}
```

Apparently, `classicthesis` redefines `\descriptionlabel` in a way that produces conflicts.

Comment: Yes it does redefine it. I was just about to provide basically the same answer.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Found a much less ugly one

Comment: Thanks! Now I have a problem with `\aclabelfont`, because I'm still using TeXLive 2013. I'll update and try again.

Comment: The workaround works perfectly with TeXLive 2016 in Ubuntu 14.04, thanks again.